# return NULL result from N1SQL in couchbase cbq cli

Tags: couchbase

in couchbase, I have a document in beer-sample bucket

it 's like following

```
{
  "uid": "kingarthur",
  "email": "kingarthur@couchbase.com",
  "interests": [
    "Holy Grail",
    "African Swallows"
  ]
}
```

while I try to get the result from my source code application, I can get the result. here is sample code

```
// Use query
query := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM `beer-sample` WHERE email=?")
email := `kingarthur@couchbase.com`
params := []interface{}{
    email}
rows, err := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(query, params)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

var row interface{}
for rows.Next(&row) {
    fmt.Printf("Row: %v", row)
}
```

but if I run N1SQL command from the cbq cli, I always get null result, anyone know why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resolve, 
it is caused by the character ``,  we must use the single quote, or double quote

```
cbq> SELECT * FROM `beer-sample` WHERE email='kingarthur@couchbase.com';
{
    "requestID": "17507176-519e-4b42-9808-aa3b855f4fb9",
    "signature": {
        "*": "*"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "beer-sample": {
                "email": "kingarthur@couchbase.com",
                "interests": [
                    "Holy Grail",
                    "African Swallows"
                ],
                "uid": "kingarthur"
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": "success",
    "metrics": {
        "elapsedTime": "7.399438091s",
        "executionTime": "7.39925411s",
        "resultCount": 1,
        "resultSize": 266
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we can export the result object in any files to import it on any target cluster using [cbimport](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbimport-json.html)?
Any help would be appreciated.